# Adding rows to a MS Access table

Tags: database, ms-access

I am using an MS access 2016 database developed by someone else. The database has a top-level table with a number field. We add data using a preformatted excel workbook importing directly in MS Access.

Since the database was developed, several levels (rows) have needed to be added to the TABLE. The context is more sampling sites than were originally compiled when the database was made.

So I thought adding some more sampling sites would be easy. I opened the TABLE and added a line for the new site. I saved the table and tried importing the data from the new site. Here is the error message:

> The changes you requested to the table were not successful because
>   they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or
>   relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain
>   duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit
>   duplicate entries and try again.

Ok researching that answer led me to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/812718) to address the Autocomplete issue. I completed the instructions there resetting the autocomplete on the top-level TABLE.

Unfortunately the same error message crops up again and now I am uncertain how to proceed.

Does this sound like a problem that anyone has previously encountered? It is so specific that is a bit hard to even describe.

Comment: Without more knowledge of the tables involved and knowing how the imported data from excel is handled it is difficult to pinpoint to the cause of the error . Are there other tables that have a unique restraints? Are the values in the column unique? If you add your table definition and more informatio (screenshot) this would help. Also if your problem is not related to vba you might be better of at superuser.com

Comment: I know I am still learning how to ask question about Access. Much harder than simply posting code. So the numbers in the columns are indeed unique. There are no other tables that have unique restraints - I don't think. Can you define unique restraint? In terms of how the data is handled, any thoughts on how to assess that?

Answer (score 0):

The data you trying to insert already exists in columns with unique indexes.
In order to understand why the error appears, you need to catch the SQL, which inserts the data to table. It may be not easy and depends on technology used in the application. I think this error generated by VBA code, which imports the data from site. Stop code execution when error message appears (Ctrl-Break), click Debug, comment `On Error GoTo ...` code line and restart import. Debugger will stop on error line. Copy SQL line and use it in query builder for analyse, try to figure out which data duplicated.

For test you can also delete unique indexes, insert the data and analyse duplicates in columns, which were indexed by unique indexes.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey S. Unfortunately that troubleshooting approach didn't work and I wasn't able to catch the SQL. The Ctrl-Break step did not produce the desired effect. Any tips on how I get around that? Because Access is GUI based I am having trouble figuring out how to illustrate my problem.

Comment: Did you try to delete indexes and analyze inserted data? After deleting this error should not appear.